# Why does saving `to_netcdf` without `encoding=` change some values to `nan`?

Tags: python, python-xarray, netcdf4

I'm struggling to understand a problem in my code when saving a `xarray.DataSet` as `netCDF`. The file does not contain any `nan` values. However after saving and loading it suddenly does for one value:

1. Before: no `nan` in the original data before saving:

   ```py
   > ds.where(lambda x: x.isnull(), drop=True).coords

   Coordinates:
     * x        (x) float64 
     * y        (y) float64 
     * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 
       lon      (x) float64 
       lat      (y) float64
   ```
2. Saving:

   ```py
   > ds.to_netcdf("manual_save.nc")
   ```
3. Loading: Now a `nan` appears for a single data entry. Only this entry is affected. The effect is reproducible.

   ```py
   > xr.open_dataset("manual_save.nc").where(lambda x: x.isnull(), drop=True).coords

   Coordinates:
     * x        (x) float64 -3.5
     * y        (y) float64 57.0
     * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2023-02-01
       lon      (x) float64 -3.5
       lat      (y) float64 57.0
   ```

*I don't understand why this is happening, can someone explain and offer a good solution?*

**More details**

1. Here's the value before and after saving+loading of the affected entry:

   ```py
   # Before saving+loading
   > ds["soil temperature"].sel(x=-3.5, y=57, time="2023-02-01 00:00").load()

   <xarray.DataArray 'soil temperature' ()>
   array(275.88766, dtype=float32)
   Coordinates:
       x        float64 -3.5
       y        float64 57.0
       time     datetime64[ns] 2023-02-01
       lon      float64 -3.5
       lat      float64 57.0
   Attributes:
       units:      K
       long_name:  Soil temperature level 4
       module:     era5
       feature:    temperature

   # After saving+loading
   > xr.open_dataset("manual_save.nc")["soil temperature"].sel(x=-3.5, y=57, time="2023-02-01 00:00").load()

   <xarray.DataArray 'soil temperature' ()>
   array(nan, dtype=float32)
   Coordinates:
       x        float64 -3.5
       y        float64 57.0
       time     datetime64[ns] 2023-02-01
       lon      float64 -3.5
       lat      float64 57.0
   Attributes:
       units:      K
       long_name:  Soil temperature level 4
       module:     era5
       feature:    temperature
   ```
2. Before saving the data is represented as a `dask.array` in `xarray`, requiring the `.load()` to show the value. Without `.load()` it looks like this before saving:

   ```py
   > ds["soil temperature"].sel(x=-3.5, y=57, time="2023-02-01 00:00")

   <xarray.DataArray 'soil temperature' ()>
   dask.array<getitem, shape=(), dtype=float32, chunksize=(), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
   Coordinates:
       x        float64 -3.5
       y        float64 57.0
       time     datetime64[ns] 2023-02-01
       lon      float64 -3.5
       lat      float64 57.0
   Attributes:
       units:      K
       long_name:  Soil temperature level 4
       module:     era5
       feature:    temperature
   ```
3. Here's a peak at the full `xarray.DataSet`. *No* other entries are affected by the problem:

   ```py
   > ds

   <xarray.Dataset>
   Dimensions:           (x: 23, y: 25, time: 48)
   Coordinates:
     * x                 (x) float64 -4.0 -3.75 -3.5 -3.25 ... 0.75 1.0 1.25 1.5
     * y                 (y) float64 56.0 56.25 56.5 56.75 ... 61.5 61.75 62.0
     * time              (time) datetime64[ns] 2023-01-31 ... 2023-02-01T23:00:00
       lon               (x) float64 -4.0 -3.75 -3.5 -3.25 ... 0.75 1.0 1.25 1.5
       lat               (y) float64 56.0 56.25 56.5 56.75 ... 61.5 61.75 62.0
   Data variables:
       temperature       (time, y, x) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(24, 25, 23), meta=np.ndarray>
       soil temperature  (time, y, x) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(24, 25, 23), meta=np.ndarray>
   Attributes:
       module:             era5
       prepared_features:  ['temperature']
       chunksize_time:     100
       Conventions:        CF-1.6
       history:            2023-03-13 09:15:56 GMT by grib_to_netcdf-2.25.1: /op...
   ```
4. I can workaround the issue by specifying an compression with `zlib` via `encoding`:

   ```py
   > ds.to_netcdf("manual_save_with_zlib.nc", encoding={'soil temperature': {'zlib': True, 'complevel': 1}})
   > xr.open_dataset("manual_save_with_zlib.nc")["soil temperature"].sel(x=-3.5, y=57, time="2023-02-01 00:00").load()

   <xarray.DataArray 'soil temperature' ()>
   array(275.88766, dtype=float32)
   Coordinates:
       x        float64 -3.5
       y        float64 57.0
       time     datetime64[ns] 2023-02-01
       lon      float64 -3.5
       lat      float64 57.0
   Attributes:
       units:      K
       long_name:  Soil temperature level 4
       module:     era5
       feature:    temperature
   ```
5. The DataSet is created quite deep [inside the code of a library of ours](https://github.com/PyPSA/atlite/blob/17c81f9bee46752a89e31d5c28dc9e0b5fb107b9/atlite/data.py#L171) from the online API of [ERA5](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-single-levels), so I don't know how to create a MWE to share for this issue. The API access and retrieved data all seem to work fine as always.
6. (edit) As suggested by psalt I tried `.compute()` before saving and explicitly specifying `compute=True` while saving to remove this potential `dask` stumbling block. Neither change the result, after loading the `nan` value still exist. Here's what I did:

   ```py
   > ds.compute().to_netcdf("manual_save_pre-compute.nc")
   > ds.to_netcdf("manual_save-and-compute.nc", compute=True)
   ```
7. (edit) I also tried saving to `zarr` but without any success either. The same problem occurs there after loading.
8. (out of date)

> ! (edit) I'm sharing the affected `DataSet` as `pickle` because all standard methods from `xarray` interfere with the problem. If you unpickle the version and then save the DataSet as described above, you can reproduce the problem. You can [download the pickle file here](https://fex.hrz.uni-giessen.de/fop/YWayEkb2/manual_save.pickle).
> !
> >!    `python >!    > import pickle >!     >!    # Code used for creating the pickle >!    > f = open("manual_save.pickle", "wb") >!    > pickle.dump(ds, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL) >!    > f.close() >!     >!    # Code for unpickling >!    with open("manual_save.pickle", "rb") as f: >!        ds = pickle.load(f)~ >!`

9. (edit) I've managed to track down the error to an instable `netCDF` file. You can [download the file here](https://fex.hrz.uni-giessen.de/fop/34z4pt2G/instable-datafile.nc). Tested with `xarray=2023.2.0` the following code seems to create a `nan` value out of thin air:

   ```py
   import xarray as xr

   ds = xr.open_mfdataset("instable-datafile.nc")
   display("This contains no nan values", ds["t2m"].values)

   ds.to_netcdf("collapsed-datafile.nc")
   display("This contains nan values", xr.open_dataset("collapsed-datafile.nc")["t2m"].values)

   # Output

   'This contains no nan values'

   array([[[278.03146, 278.4846 ],
           [278.50998, 278.6799 ]],

           [[277.91476, 278.4109 ],
           [278.36594, 278.571  ]]], dtype=float32)

   'This contains nan values'

   array([[[278.03146, 278.4846 ],
           [278.50998, 278.6799 ]],

           [[      nan, 278.4109 ],
           [278.36594, 278.571  ]]], dtype=float32)
   ```

I'm happy to provide more information. Just let me know.

Comment: It's weird the NaN only occours for one data point, but without having the file I cannot reproduce this. It looks like it could be a problem with dask? Have you tried to use `.compute()` before saving or set `compute=True` in `.to_netcdf()`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried both without success. I've shared the `DataSet`, see the download link in the edited post under 7.. (I know, the whole problem it looks weird. It also feels weird)

Comment: Thanks for uploading the file, unfortunately I cannot load the file with pickle: `AttributeError: 'PandasIndex' object has no attribute 'index'`

Comment: I've no problems opening it and also asked a colleague who can open it without problems. Maybe we have mismatching libraries installed? I'm running on `python=3.11.0` with `pandas=1.5.1` and `xarray=2022.11.0` both installed from `conda-forge`.

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed a version issue. However, `dask` uses a temporary directory which is not present on my drive. Because of this I cannot save to netCDF `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpia3fp7gl/tmpvh2ye7fk.nc'` . I can read the content though. I fear sharing the data as pickle will not work to reproduce the problem :/

Comment: Strange, I didn't encounter the problem with my colleague. Anyways, then we need a new plan. Do you have an idea what other format to use? I can't think of a way to use `netCDF` or `zarr` without affecting the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way I can think of is recreating the dataset from scratch from within your module and create a github issue, but I don't know if I can help in the end. Most effective would be probably to raise an issue in the module repo that's causing the bug (I'd suggest the order dask->netCDF4->xarray). However you would need a reproducible example as well.

Comment: I'm not yet sure which package actually causes the bug. I've been breaking down our whole package for the past days and found a file with which I can reproduce the issue. Let's give it another shot, see the download link under 9. in my edited post. Let me know if you can reproduce the issue with this netCDF file! TIA

Comment: I can in fact reproduce the behaviour. I think this is rather a netCDF problem, than a Python thing. I viewed the file with Panoply and the NaN already appears in the `instable-file.nc`. I will see if I can do some further checks on my Linux work PC soon. Is this an unaltered file directly retrieved from ECMWF? Via CDS? ERA5-Land hourly?

Comment: Yes, downloaded from CDS via the python `cdsapi`, ERA5, specifically `product="reanalysis-era5-single-levels"`. Happy to share the `request` if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played around with your file and found the reason for the odd behaviour. This seems to be a bug in xarray, incorrectly handling scaling factor and offset of netCDFs. Deeper down it is related with Python floating point precision.
You can find a workaround for your problem at the bottom of the post.

**scale_factor and offset**

Variables in netCDFs can be encoded with the attributes `scale_factor` and `add_offset`. This allows to store the data for example as type `short`, ranging from -32768 to +32767, saving a lot of space over using `float`.
Consider the relevant output of

`$ ncdump instable-datafile.nc`

```
variables:
        short t2m(time, latitude, longitude) ;
                t2m:scale_factor = 1.16753614203674e-05 ;
                t2m:add_offset = 278.297319296597 ;
                t2m:_FillValue = -32767s ;
                t2m:missing_value = -32767s ;
                t2m:units = "K" ;
                t2m:long_name = "2 metre temperature" ;

 t2m =
  -22772, 16038,
  18213, 32767,
  -32766, 9725,
  5877, 23442 ;
```

**How xarray deals with scale_factor and offset**

The values for the variable `t2m` are stored as `short`, when you open the netCDF with xarray, scale_factor and add_offset are applied following the formula:

`value*scale_factor+add_offset`

xarray shows the following content of the `t2m`:

```py
import xarray as xr
>>> ds = xr.open_dataset("instable-datafile.nc")
>>> ds["t2m"].values
array([[[278.03146, 278.4846 ],
        [278.50998, 278.6799 ]],

       [[277.91476, 278.4109 ],
        [278.36594, 278.571  ]]], dtype=float32)
```

When you save this dataset with xarray using `to_netcdf()`, it "packs" the values again using the scale_factor and offset, but this time the other way round.

Let's revert the equation above, apply it on the values and see what happens:

```
py
>>> scale_factor = 1.16753614203674e-05
>>> add_offset = 278.297319296597
>>> (ds["t2m"].values-add_offset)/scale_factor

array([[[-22771.812,  16038.549],
        [ 18213.268,  32767.152]],

       [[-32767.152,   9726.115],
        [  5875.922,  23440.955]]], dtype=float32)
```

**The problem**

As you can see, the numbers changed slightly, compared to the output form ncdump above. This has to do with [floating point precision](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

You can see that the dtype of the array is still `np.float32`. When we save the dataset, t2m gets of course stored again as type `short`.
This is not too problematic, because unpacking these values again will lead to differences in `t2m` at decimal places we don't care about. In fact we do not even notice, xarray shows you just the first 4 or 5 decimals.

Now, why is this specific value `NaN`? This has to do with with the `_FillValue` and the `MissingValue` attributes.
For `t2m`, the `_FillValue` is set to -32767. If you look at the calculation above, this is exactly the value that is packed by xarray's `.to_netcdf()`

**A workaround**

If we convert the data to `float64`, we can increase the precision of the data and prevent the unwanted behaviour, however this has the downside that we lose the encoding of "t2m", including `scale_factor` and `add_offset`. This is undesirably, as we cannot preserve the compression.

```py
>>> ds["t2m"] = ds["t2m"].astype(np.float64)
>>> ds["t2m"]
array([[[278.0314636230469, 278.4845886230469],
        [278.5099792480469, 278.6799011230469]],

       [[277.9147644042969, 278.410888671875 ],
        [278.3659362792969, 278.5710144042969]]])

>>> ds.to_netcdf("stable-datafile.nc")
```

`ncdump` output:

```
 t2m =
  278.031463623047, 278.484588623047,
  278.509979248047, 278.679901123047,
  277.914764404297, 278.410888671875,
  278.365936279297, 278.571014404297 ;
```

There is an [ongoing issue](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/7691) in the xarray repository, so this problem might have a better solution in the future.

Comment: Wow, I did not expect that. 1.) Could you elaborate why loosing `scale_factor` and `add_offset` would be a downside? 2.) This helps me to understand why - if I save with `.to_netcdf(..., encoding={"t2m":{"zlib":True,"complevel":4}})` - the `NaN` don't appear: The command changes the datatype and losses `scale_factor` and `add_offset`. Could you add that to your answer as well (that was the original question). 3.) Should this be reported as bug to `xarray`?

Comment: Instead of converting the data as you suggested, I decided to remove the encoding instead: `ds["t2m"].encoding.clear()`. This is sufficient to lead `xarray` to keep the values encoded as `float` instead of converting them to `short` for the netcdf file. (data conversion also resets the `endocing` dict among others. I also opened up an issue on GH (https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/7691). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Thanks a lot for raising an issue in the xarray repo. I added the link to my post.